Dynamic programming with Markov processes
Let $\{X(t),\mathcal{F}_t,0\le t\le T\}$ be a non-negative Feller process (therefore also a strong Markov process) and suppose that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the natural filtration of $X(t)$. Denote by $S_{s,t}$ the set of stopping times taking values in $[s,t]$.
A crucial result in dynamic programming theory, which has been applied to mathematical finance, states that for bounded measurable function $\phi$:$$\underset{\tau\in S_{s,t}}{\mathrm{esssup}}\mathbf{E}^x[\phi(X(\tau))|\mathcal{F}_s]=\underset{\sigma\in S_{0,t-s}}{\mathrm{esssup}}\mathbf{E}^{X(s)}[\phi(X(\sigma))]$$ I wonder why is this statement true.
I have tried to prove that, for a given $\tau\in S_{s,t}$, there exists $\sigma\in S_{0,t-s}$ such that $\mathbf{E}^x[\phi(X(\tau))|\mathcal{F}_s]=\mathbf{E}^{X(s)}[\phi(X(\sigma))]$. Using shift operators, this equality is equivalent to $$\mathbf{E}^x[\phi(X(\tau(\omega),\omega))|\mathcal{F}_s]=\mathbf{E}^x[\phi(X(\sigma(\theta_s\omega),\theta_s\omega))|\mathcal{F}_s]$$ A sufficient condition for this equality to hold is the existence of $\sigma\in S_{0,t-s}$ such that $\tau=s+\sigma\circ\theta_s$. However, the existense of such a $\sigma\in S_{0,t-s}$ would imply $$X(t,\omega_1)=X(t,\omega_2),\;\;\forall t\ge s \qquad \Rightarrow\qquad \tau(\omega_1)=\tau(\omega_2)$$which does not seem to be true.
Please help by correcting my clue or giving a direct proof to the dynamic programming equation.

In dynamic programming, proving these types of equalities directly is often extremely difficult and requires measurable selection arguments.  Instead, they are often used as a heuristic to find a "candidate solution," which is then proved to be optimal for the particular problem.
